# Why say "dame la mano" instead of "dame tu mano"?

Tags: gramática, artículos, posesivos

"Dame la mano" would mean "give me the hand". Shouldn't it be better to say "give me your hand" by saying "dame tu mano"?

For reference this is the entire phrase coming from spanishdict:
"Dame la mano, no vayas a perderte entre tanta gente."

Comment: > "Shouldn't it be better...?" Only if we assume that English idioms are better :-)

Comment: You'd be understood with "dame tu mano," but it wouldn't sound good.  // Here's a song that might help you get used to this idiom: https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=891887, https://youtu.be/-GG7AB3EwPg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"dar la mano" is an idiom. Although we can hear:

- Dame tu mano.

it's more idiomatic, as well as more logical, to say:

- Dame **la** mano. (Who else's hand would you give me if not yours? -- that is, unless we are speaking about somebody's severed hand!)

In Spanish, we tend to use articles rather than possessives with parts of the body in direct object position. This is not only the case with reflexive actions but also with actions performed on others. We prefer to use a pronoun to indicate the recipient of the action and an article rather than the possesive. (Notice the ambiguity with the English possessive in the sentences between parentheses below.)

We thus say:

- **Se** lavó **la** cara. (He/She washed his/her (own) face.)
- **Le** lavó **la** cara (He/She washed his/her (somebody else's) face).
- **Se** tocó **la** frente. (He/She touched his/her (own) forehead.)
- **Le** tocó **la** frente. (He/She touched his/her (somebody else's) forehead.)
- **Se** tapó **los** ojos. (He/She covered his/her (own) eyes.)
- **Le** tapó **los** ojos. (He/She covered his/her (somebody else's) eyes.)
- **Se** cortó **el** pelo. (He/She cut his/her (own) hair -- or had it cut.)
- **Le** cortó **el** pelo. (He/She cut his/her (somebody else's) hair.)

We only don't use a pronoun when our hands or fingers do not touch the part of the body involved. In these cases, English uses a possessive, while Spanish requires an article:

- Abrió/Cerró **los** ojos. (He/She opened/closed his/her (own) eyes.)
- Movió **la** cabeza. (He/She moved his/her (own) head.)
- Levantó/Agitó **la** mano. (He/She raised/waved his/her (own) hand.)
- Dobló **las** rodillas. (He/She bent his/her (own) knees.)
- Cruzó **los** brazos/**las** piernas (also: **Se** cruzó de brazos/de piernas) (He/She crossed his/her (own) legs/arms.)

Comment: I could do without the severed hand....

Comment: @aparente001 I was just trying to be humorous. It could also be the case of somebody letting you have the hand of somebody who would not offer you his/her hand voluntarily (a child, a disabled person, an unconscious person).

Comment: Call me squeamish.

Comment: @Gustavson Would it then mean that if you're talking about someone's severed hand or the hand of somebody who would not offer you his/her hand voluntarily you would use "dame su mano", would you use a possessive or an article? Thank you for the great answer by the way.

Comment: @Louis A possessive would be used in that case: *Dame/Muéstrame **su** mano*.