# the function of the definite article instead of the possessive adjective

Tags: artículos

I was reading the sentence:

> Me he torcido el tobillo.

which translates to

> I have twisted my ankle.

From an English perspective, I was wondering why Spanish uses the definite article `el`, the definite article instead of `mi`, the personal possessive adjective before the noun.

Another example where this left me stumped was

> Me he roto el brazo.

I understand that it is simply wiser to learn the structure of grammar as it is, but it would be far easier to learn if there was a reasonable explanation or any viable reason why this is the case instead of just "that's how Spanish is."

Comment: You may find the answer to your question here: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23915/why-say-dame-la-mano-instead-of-dame-tu-mano/23919#23919

Comment: I Think this is mostly because normally we won't use possesive pronouns to indicate possesion of highly obvious objects when, and also because we are already using the reflexive pronoun to indicate who is affected/.